# Cannot properly execute bash script because of a redirection in an environment where root is the owner

Tags: bash, redirect, find, append, sudo

My script is executable and I run it as sudo. I tried many workarounds and alternatives to the ">>" operator but nothing seemed to work properly.

My script:

```
#! /bin/bash
if [[ -z "$1" || -z "$2" ]]; then
  exit 1
else
  root=$1
  fileExtension=$2
fi
$(sudo find $root -regex ".*\.${fileExtension}") >> /home/mux/Desktop/AllFilesOf${fileExtension}.txt
```

I tried tee, sed and dd of, I also tried running it with bash -c or in sudo -i , nothing worked. Either i get an empty file or a Permission denied error.
I searched thoroughly and read many command manuals but I can't get it to work

Comment: "Tried `tee`" **how**, exactly? You need to apply the `sudo` to the `tee` command; you can't `sudo ... | tee outfile` and expect it to work, it needs to be `sudo ... | sudo tee outfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$()` operator performs *command substitution*.  When the overall command line is expanded, the command within the parentheses is executed, and the whole construct is replaced with the command's output.  After all expansions are performed, the resulting line is executed as a command.

Consider, then, this simplified version of your command:

```
$(find /etc -regex ".*\.conf") >> /home/mux/Desktop/AllFilesOfconf.txt
```

On my system that will expand to a ginormous command of the form

```
/etc/rsyslog.conf /etc/pnm2ppa.conf ... /etc/updatedb.conf >> /home/mux/Desktop/AllFilesOfconf.txt
```

Note at this point that the redirection is separate from, and therefore independent of, the command in the command substitution.  Expanding the command substitution therefore does not cause anything to be written to the target file.

But we're not done!  That was just the expansion.  Bash now tries to execute the result as a command.  In particular, in the above example it tries to execute `/etc/rsyslog.conf` as a command, with all the other file names as arguments, and with output redirected as specified.  But `/etc/rsyslog.conf` is not executable, so that will fail, producing a "permission denied" message.  I'm sure you can extrapolate from there what effects different expansions would produce.

I don't think you mean to perform a command substitution at all, but rather just to run the command and redirect its output to the given file.  That would simply be this:

```
sudo find $root -regex ".*\.${fileExtension}" >> /home/mux/Desktop/AllFilesOf${fileExtension}.txt
```

***Update:***

As @CharlesDuffy observed, the redirection in that case is performed with the permissions of the user / process running the script, just as it is in your original example.  I have supposed that that is intentional and correct -- i.e. that the script is being run by user 'mux' or by another user that has access to mux's `Desktop` directory and to any existing file in it that the script might try to create or update.  If that is not the case, and you need the redirection, too, to be privileged, then you can achieve it like so:

```
sudo -s <<END
find $root -regex ".*\.${fileExtension}" >> /home/mux/Desktop/AllFilesOf${fileExtension}.txt
END
```

That runs an interactive shell via `sudo`, with its input is redirected from the heredoc.  The variable expansions are performed in the host shell from which sudo is executed.  In this case the redirection is performed with the identity obtained via `sudo`, which affects access control, as well as ownership of the file if a new one is created.  You could add a `chown` command if you don't want the output files to be owned by root.

Comment: That still doesn't apply the `sudo` to the redirection itself, and thus doesn't solve the OP's problem w/ not being able to open the output file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, it's not clear to me that the problem is inability to open the output file.  The permission denied message likely arises from an attempt to execute a file that is not executable.  In fact, he says he sometimes gets an empty file; if he started with *no* file then that indicates that the file is, indeed, opened.

Comment: Anyhow -- this is clearly correct insofar as it goes -- it fixes something that's without doubt a problem; it simply may or may not be the only problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I have updated the answer to provide a mechanism by which the redirection is performed with increased privilege as well.  I'm still doubtful that this is needed, and because of the effects on ownership of any new file created it might not even be wanted, but it's there.

Comment: @John Bollinger Thank you very much for your correct and quick answer. The promblem was indeed that I tried to execute the result of the find command. Now that I know it, I feel kind of stupid. I am relatively new to Linux and programming/scripting, but since I am eager to learn I tried this sript "just4fun". Anyways thank you for your help. You are a great asset to this community. :).. and thanks to CharlesDuffy too for the healthy scepticism.